How to extract values from a delimited data in DB2?
I have this table of data:
BILL_TYPE                        + BILL_DATE                           + BILL_STATUS
---------------------------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------
EXPECTED]PAYMENT]PAYMENT^PAYMENT + 20230901]20230908]20230915^20230915 + SETTLED]CAPITALISE]CAPITALISE^SETTLED

Each value separated by ] or ^ should become a piece of information in the same row, as shown in the table below:
BILL TYPE        + BILL_DATE + BILL_STATUS
-----------------+-----------+--------------
EXPECTED           20230901    SETTLED
PAYMENT            20230908    CAPITALISE
PAYMENT            20230915    CAPITALISE
PAYMENT            20230915    SETTLED

I have tried separating the values in each table cell using the following XMTABLE function for the ] and ^ separators.
XMLTABLE('$doc/items/item'
              PASSING XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT CAST('<items><item><value>'||REPLACE(column_name,']','</value></item><item><value>')||'</value></item></items>' as CLOB)) as "doc"
              new_column_name
              ITEM VARCHAR(255) PATH 'value'
          )

and here's the result:
BILL TYPE    + BILL DATE + BILL_STATUS
-------------+-----------+--------------
20230901       EXPECTED    SETTLED
20230901       EXPECTED    SETTLED
20230901       EXPECTED    SETTLED
20230901       EXPECTED    SETTLED
20230901       PAYMENT     SETTLED
20230901       PAYMENT     SETTLED
20230901       PAYMENT     SETTLED
20230901       PAYMENT     SETTLED
20230908       EXPECTED    SETTLED
20230908       EXPECTED    SETTLED
20230908       EXPECTED    SETTLED
20230908       EXPECTED    SETTLED
20230908       PAYMENT     SETTLED
20230908       PAYMENT     SETTLED
20230908       PAYMENT     SETTLED
20230908       PAYMENT     SETTLED
20230915       EXPECTED    SETTLED
20230915       EXPECTED    SETTLED
20230915       EXPECTED    SETTLED
20230915       EXPECTED    SETTLED
20230915       PAYMENT     SETTLED
20230915       PAYMENT     SETTLED
20230915       PAYMENT     SETTLED
20230915       PAYMENT     SETTLED
20230901       EXPECTED    CAPITALISE
20230901       EXPECTED    CAPITALISE
20230901       EXPECTED    CAPITALISE
20230901       EXPECTED    CAPITALISE
20230901       PAYMENT     CAPITALISE
20230901       PAYMENT     CAPITALISE
20230901       PAYMENT     CAPITALISE
20230901       PAYMENT     CAPITALISE
20230908       EXPECTED    CAPITALISE
20230908       EXPECTED    CAPITALISE
20230908       EXPECTED    CAPITALISE
20230908       EXPECTED    CAPITALISE
20230908       PAYMENT     CAPITALISE
20230908       PAYMENT     CAPITALISE
20230908       PAYMENT     CAPITALISE
20230908       PAYMENT     CAPITALISE
20230915       EXPECTED    CAPITALISE
20230915       EXPECTED    CAPITALISE
20230915       EXPECTED    CAPITALISE
20230915       EXPECTED    CAPITALISE
20230915       PAYMENT     CAPITALISE
20230915       PAYMENT     CAPITALISE
20230915       PAYMENT     CAPITALISE
20230915       PAYMENT     CAPITALISE

I feel like the result is as if I am using the CROSS JOIN function, which is not the result I want.
As my expected results were only 4 rows:
BILL TYPE        + BILL DATE + BILL_STATUS
-----------------+-----------+--------------
EXPECTED           20230901    SETTLED
PAYMENT            20230908    CAPITALISE
PAYMENT            20230915    CAPITALISE
PAYMENT            20230915    SETTLED

what function should I use? I'm thinking I should use some kind of flag but I don't know what function to use.
Here's my dbfiddle : https://dbfiddle.uk/tM5LebOM

This question is similar to: how to transform comma separated column into multiples rows in db2. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This has been asked many times on SO.  And if your Platform/Version of Db2 includes a Split() function...it is even easier.

This works with DB2 for i (at V7R2), don't know about LUW:
    with data (s) as (values
('EXPECTED]PAYMENT]PAYMENT^PAYMENT + 20230901]20230908]' concat
 '20230915^20230915 + SETTLED]CAPITALISE]CAPITALISE^SETTLED')
),
     split (block,posi,val) as (
select b,
       p,
       regexp_substr(
           regexp_substr(s,'[^ +]+', 1, b),
           '\w+', 1, p)
from   data
cross  join (values (1),(2),(3),(4)) x (b)
cross  join (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) y (p)
-- 3 blocks separated by ' + '
where  b <= regexp_count(s,'[^ +]+')
-- 4 values within one block
and    p <= regexp_count(regexp_substr(s,'[^ +]+', 1, b),'\w+') 
)
select listagg(val,' ') within group (order by posi,block)
from   split
group  by posi
order  by posi

